# Python ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 at df_num = list(map(int, df))

Tags: python, pandas, integer, covariance, literals

I want to implement a covariance matrix from scratch. I got an error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`,

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Downloads/Admission_Predict.csv')

df = df.sample(frac=1)
mean = df.mean()
cov = {}

for j in range(len(mean)):
    total = 0
    for k in range(len(mean)):

        # Use Pearson correlation for interval variables
        terms = ((df.iloc[i, j] - mean.iloc[j]) * (df.iloc[i, k] - mean.iloc[k]) for i in range(len(mean)))
        covariance = sum(terms) / (len(mean) - 1)
        df_num = list(map(int, df))
        st_dev = statistics.pstdev(df_num)
        pearson = covariance[j, k] / (st_dev(j) * st_dev(k))

        # If feature k is already in dict, append Pearson. Else, apply feature k as a list object.
        if k in cov:
            cov[k].append(pearson)
        else:
            cov[k] = [pearson]

# Coerce the cov list into a dataframe
cov_df = pd.DataFrame(cov)

# rename the columns of the cov dataframe
col_dict = {}
for idx, col in enumerate(cov_df.columns):
    col_dict[idx] = col
cov_df = cov_df.rename(index=col_dict)

print(cov_df)


> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\algorithms\mod2.py", line 17, in
> <module>
>     df_num = list(map(int, df)) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'GRE Score'
```

I've tried to cast the string using `astype` but it raised a type error.

```
df_num = df.astype(int)
```

> `TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator`

Output: I want to emulate the output from `pandas.corr()`

```
corr = df.corr()
print(corr)
```

> ```
>                    GRE Score  TOEFL Score  ...  Research  Chance of Admit
> GRE Score           1.000000     0.835977  ...  0.580391         0.802610
> TOEFL Score         0.835977     1.000000  ...  0.489858         0.791594
> University Rating   0.668976     0.695590  ...  0.447783         0.711250
> SOP                 0.612831     0.657981  ...  0.444029         0.675732
> LOR                 0.557555     0.567721  ...  0.396859         0.669889
> CGPA                0.833060     0.828417  ...  0.521654         0.873289
> Research            0.580391     0.489858  ...  1.000000         0.553202
> Chance of Admit     0.802610     0.791594  ...  0.553202         1.000000
>
> [8 rows x 8 columns]
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
        df_num = list(map(int, df))
```

Try:

```
        df_num = df.astype(int)
```